# Kivy how to get rid of a block once a collision is made

Tags: python, kivy

So I've making brick breaker the game in Livy I don't know how to get the brick to disappear and become disabled  so I don't know how to set it up so that the ball hit it.
It disappears and can't interact with the ball again

## Python code

```
class Block(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.0
            ball.velocity = vel.y, vel.x + offset


class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.0
            ball.velocity = vel.y, vel.x + offset


class PongBall(Widget):
    ball = image
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    brick = ObjectProperty(None)
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    block = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(0, 4)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        #bounce of paddles
        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        if self.block.bounce_ball(self.ball): self.dispatch

        #bounce ball off bottom or top
        if (self.ball.top > self.top):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

        #bounce ball off bottom or top
        if (self.ball.x < 0) or (self.ball.right > self.width):
            self.ball.velocity_x *= -1

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x > self.width / 12:
            self.player1.center_x = touch.x       


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 30.0)       
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

## kv file

```
<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50 
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            source: 'MinecraftBall.png'
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size  

<Block>:
    size: 100, 20
    pos: 300, 400
    opacity: .5
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'dirt.png'
            pos:self.pos
            size: 100, 20

<PongPaddle>:
    size: 200, 25
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos 
            size:self.size

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    player1: player_left
    block: block_destroy

    canvas:
        #Ellipse:
        Video:
            size: root.size
            pos: root.pos
            allow_stretch: True
            source: 'H:/2d app/project/NaturalWorld.avi'
            play: True

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center

    PongPaddle:
        id: player_left
        x: root.x
        center_x: root.center_x

    Block:
        id: block_destroy
        x: root.x
        center_x: root.center_x
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code? So we do not have to guess...

Comment: there you go i put in my code